# Servlet Error: StandardWrapperValve[Login]: Allocate exception for servlet

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I'm a newbie programming with Java and I was doing JSP/Databases exercises when problems started.
I have a project which works if I open it in NetBeans 8.2, but it doesn't work if I try run it in NetBeans 12.3 because servlets don't work (in 11 version worked). I always use GlassFish (in case it was important).

Even "Test" servlet, with default content, shows same error. I would like to know what is the cause of the error in the version that I currently use so that I can fix it.

This is the error message in navigator:
[image: Navigator message error]

This is the error message in Output of GlassFish Server:
[image: Output error]

And this is my web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Prueba</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.Prueba</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registrar</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.Registrar</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CrearPelicula</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.CrearPelicula</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EliminarPelicula</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.EliminarPelicula</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CerrarSesion</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controlador.CerrarSesion</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Prueba</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prueba</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registrar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registrar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrearPelicula</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/crearPelicula</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EliminarPelicula</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/eliminarPelicula</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CerrarSesion</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cerrarSesion</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```